Не работают команды wsl в cmd, связано ли это с выключенным компонентом "Подсистема windows для linux"?
0
Всем здравствуйте. Столкнулся с проблемой что командная строка не выполняет команды wsl. К примеру возьму команду wsl --list --verbose в результате ее выполнения получу следующий вывод :
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation). Все права защищены.

Использование: wsl.exe [Аргумент]

Аргументы:

    --install <Options>
        Установка компонентов подсистемы Windows для Linux. Если параметры не указаны,
        рекомендуемые компоненты будут установлены вместе с дистрибутивом по умолчанию.

        Чтобы просмотреть дистрибутив по умолчанию, а также список других допустимых дистрибутивов,
        используйте "wsl --list --online".

        Параметры:
            --distribution, -d [Аргумент]
                Указывает дистрибутив для скачивания и установки по имени.

                Аргументы:
                    Допустимое имя дистрибутива (без учета регистра).

                Примеры:
                    wsl --install -d Ubuntu
                    wsl --install --distribution Debian

            --inbox
                Установка необязательного компонента Windows вместо версии, доступной в Microsoft Store.

            --enable-wsl1
                Включение поддержки WSL1 в версии Microsoft Store.

            --no-distribution
                Не устанавливать дистрибутив (не может использоваться с параметром --distribution).

            --no-launch, -n
                Не запускать дистрибутив после установки.

            --web-download
                Скачать последнюю версию WSL из Интернета вместо Microsoft Store.

    --list, -l [параметры]
        Перечисление дистрибутивов.

        Параметры:
            --online, -o
                Отображение списка дистрибутивов, доступных для установки с помощью команды "wsl --install".

    --status
        Показать состояние подсистемы Windows для Linux.

    --help
        Вывод сведений об использовании.

Может ли данное явление быть связанным с тем, что в "Панель управления" > "Программы" > "Включение или отключение компонентов Windows" не установлена галочка напротив компонента  "Подсистема Windows для Linux"?

Скорее всего. У меня то же самое.

Подсистема Windows для Linux это наоборот вроде

@eri Кто бы мог подумать?

@rotabor пробовали галочку ставить напротив подсистемы?

А сам-то пробовал?

А оно тебе зачем? Напоминает анекдот: Сережа поставил себе Линукс и всю ночь трахался с драйверами, а Коля поставил Windows Маше и всю ночь трахался с Машей.

Ну если трах нужен постоянно, то лучше поставить Линукс маше. Он не ломается, но всегда есть повод зайти в гости)

сам не пробовал, боюсь что линукс мне установится)) а вообще эта штука нужна для докера вроде, мол без нее работать не будет. Анекдот классный)
